# Application manifests: will adding one undo the changes Program Compatibility Assistant made, and do I merge it with a Visual Styles manifest?

Tags: winapi, manifest

There is a bug in my test program that causes an API call to fail when I click the Close button on its main window. The error reporting prints the error and calls `DebugBreak()`. I choose to close the application when Windows asks what to do. After it does so, however, this dialog pops up:

[image: Program Compatibility Assistant dialog, not the installer one]

telling me that Windows thinks the program is not compatible with Windows and that some compatibility fixes have been applied.

I know that this bug is not affected by the compatibility fixes, and I do intend on fixing it. However, I am afraid that this will affect other bugs that I may not know about yet, and my program requires Vista SP2+Platform Update (I should just bump it to 7 as well...), so running in a compatibility mode is undesired.

The executable is on a network drive.

I know that I can fix this with an application compatibility manifest, which neither the test program nor the DLL it uses have. So my first question is: **will applying the manifest alone be enough to undo the compatibility changes, or do I have to go into the Registry and manually remove whatever PCA changed (or disable PCA outright)?**

Second, I already have a Common Controls 6 manifest. Do I just slip the `<compatibility>` block at the end of that manifest, or do I need two separate manifests for this? Or in other words, is this correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>Your application description here.</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application> 
</compatibility>
</assembly>
```

as the `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID` resource?

And finally, if I do do the above, how can I verify that PCA modifications aren't being applied anymore?

This is Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a bug in my test program

Then why not fix the bug, instead of trying to work around it?

> Do I just slip the  block at the end of that manifest

Yes

> do I need two separate manifests for this

No. There can only be one manifest for the executable, so it needs to contain everything. Visual Studio allows you to specify some manifest contents in separate pieces, which it then merges together into the final resource.

Comment: I should have explained; yes, I do have to fix the bug, but I am afraid the compatibility patch would mask other bugs as well! (I know that it does not affect this one. I know what's going on but not why it's happening; it has to do with a child window being destroyed prematurely, though.) Thanks though; I edited the question to add that context in the meantime.

Comment: Okay, I added the manifest, had the program crash, then took it off and crashed it again; the compatibility dialog did not come back. So how can I know that the compatibility fixes aren't being applied anymore?